# MOOTOOLS calling sexy.error() from PHP

Tags: php, mootools

I am very inexperienced with PHP and I've having trouble calling a mootools function.

Here's my code:

```
echo '<script language="JavaScript">'; 
echo "Sexy.error('Test!');"; 
echo '</script>';
```

When viewing source code looks like this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Bath Solutions</title> 

    <link xmlns="" href="html_includes/css/main.css?version=10.03.05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
    <link xmlns="" href="html_includes/mootools/Autocompleter.css?version=10.03.05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

    <link xmlns="" href="html_includes/css/print.css?version=10.03.05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" /><link xmlns="" href="html_includes/css/schedule.css?version=10.03.05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />   
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/mootools.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/main.js.php?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/datepicker.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/mootools/Observer.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/mootools/Autocompleter.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/mootools/Autocompleter.Request.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/mootools/sexyalert/sexyalertbox.v1.2.moo.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="html_includes/mootools/sexyalert/sexyalertbox.css?version=10.03.05"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html_includes/fckeditor/fckeditor.js?version=10.03.05"></script> 

</head>
<body> 
<script language="JavaScript">Sexy.error('Test!');</script>
...
```

When I try it with a simple `alert('test')` it works just fine.. I'm confused?!?

UPDATE: I tried a calling the `Sexy.error()` `onClick` in an anchor tag and it works fine:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Sexy.error('test');return false;">click to test</a>
```

Comment: have you include the mootols where you are using that code?

Comment: yep--it works fine on other pages, I am adding additional functionality to an existing project, all pages pull through index.php to grab header and footer, db connection etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the call into a domready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent("domready", function() {
    Sexy.error('test');
});
</script>
```

if the class depends on any part of the dom, like `<div id='sexy'></div>` being 'there', it won't work as is--at the time of running of the script block, the target div won't be available for DOM manipulations yet.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your version of mootools, but according to [this](http://www.coders.me/lang/en/web-html-js-css/javascript/sexy-alert-box-12-mootools-jquery) there is not `error` method. Try changing your code to:

```
echo '<script language="JavaScript">';   
echo "Sexy.alert('Test!');";   
echo '</script>';
```

instead.

and remember to add this to your html too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sexyalertbox.v1.2.moo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="sexyalertbox.css"/>
```

Comment: maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet but I don't see a difference in code...lol! It's not the includes as there all setup by index.php and I can see them when I view source

Comment: lol.. i c now, there is an error method though. I did try the Alert method however didn't work.

http://translate.google.ca/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://www.bsisplash.com/html_includes/mootools/sexyalert/&sl=es&tl=en

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn how to use FireBug - will help you greatly in such cases.

Comment: Thanks but I use dev verison of Chrome, and console is giving no clues